# Android - No Activity found (What am I missing and How did you know)

Tags: android

**SOLUTION:**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Specials"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

OK the infamous "No Activity Found" error.

**Button:**

```
Button btnSpecials = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpecials);
    btnSpecials.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS")); 
        }
    });
```

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Specials" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPECIALS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Log Cat:**

```
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS }
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3057)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2837)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.Home_Page$1.onClick(Home_Page.java:49)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
05-16 09:44:50.149: E/AndroidRuntime(17747): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:**

In response to some of your answers, I have another app that uses the the following code and it is working fine.  This is why I am on here asking.  I want to do this the right way.

Also my .java file is Specials.java

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".mainAboutUs" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.kita.PapaStew.MAINABOUTUS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**ADDING FULL MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:name="StoredValues"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />

    <receiver
        android:name="C2DMReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MyGardenCenterAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".myTabbar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.MYTABBAR" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home_Page"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HOMEPAGE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Notification"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Calendar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALENDAR" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Facebook"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.FACEBOOK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Map_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAPACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".More"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MORE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Twitter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TWITTER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Website"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEBSITE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Google_Plus"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GOOGLEPLUS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Notes"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTES" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Feedback"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.FEEDBACK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Ask_the_Expert"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASKTHEEXPERT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Tips"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIPS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Just_In"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.JUSTIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Calulators"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALCULATORS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: The check is tough on this one but this was the closest to what I did.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not added new created activity to your manifest file

just add it as

```
<activity
        android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".Specials" >
```

Should be

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".SPECIALS" >
```

Or vice-versa, you're breaking [naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java) by upper casing the class name.

Also, your intent-filter is off.

As the other answers state you need to change the action in your intent-filter to:

```
<action android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS" />
```

Comment: Is your class name the upper case `SPECIALS`? like.. `public class SPECIALS extends Activity {` ?

Comment: no its Specials.java  so public class Specials extends Activity {

Comment: Remember about case-sensitivity

Comment: According to that link you posted class names are UpperCase CamelHump.  So are you talking about the  <action android:name="com.kita.MyGardenCenterApp.SPECIALS" /> ? The SPECIALS I was under the impression this had to always be all uppercase.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11333/discussion-between-sabanim-and-styler)